# watershed segmentation implementation using scikit image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, watershed

I have [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcYlc.jpg) with certain overlapping. I want to segment it with watershed algorithm using distance transform but are not able to achieve it.

I am following the steps

1. distance transform on binary image,
2. then dilation and opening and finally
3. watershed.

I an new to this field, kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with OpenCV and something like [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html), but it's in C++ which isn't a very friendly language.  Alternatively, if you use python, here's a [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/) that demonstrates watershed. PyImageSearch is pretty new-programmer-friendly and has some great tutorials on image processing with Python.

Comment: but point i got stuck is selection of markers, using distance transform,i found local maxima as marker and directly using them for  watershed, still not satisfacoty result with this operation

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without seeing source code.